# Ubuntu 22.04 not loading UI after login, getting black screen

Tags: boot, login, hdmi, gui

I'm having trouble with the system UI not loading after login. A few days ago I restarted my computer and got the login screen as expected, clicked on my user, typed my password and the UI did not load, got a black screen. Then I pressed the shutdown button for 10 seconds to force a restart, got the login screen back, typed my password, got same black screen. Repeated this process for like 5 more times and got the same thing. Then out of frustration I was like I'm going to wait the black screen for a while, waited in the black screen for around 30 minutes, nothing happened.

Then I unplugged my HDMI cable that connect to my second monitor to test if that could be the problem. Still same thing, after login I got a black screen. I restarted it again a few more times and same error. So in a lucky move (lucky because I was leaning towards format whole thing and install ubuntu again), in the login screen, I connected my HDMI cable before typing my password...then typed password, pressed enter and *voila*: Ubuntu UI was on.

So today, this problem happened again, I had to restart my computer to apply a Ubuntu update, after restart I got the login screen, typed my password and black screen. I pressed the shutdown button for 10 seconds to force and restart, in the login screen I got into terminal (ctrl+alt+F3) to see some settings, I was getting error like: `xhost unable to open display`. Searching online got some info to see $DISPLAY variable, `echo $DISPLAY` did show nothing was set, I tried setting it to :0, :0.0 and :1, neither worked. Also tried the command `who` that did show my user and tty1 in front of it. I tried to set $DISPLAY to tty1 and still same error xhost unable to open display. Other things I tried was to reinstall ubuntu-desktop, `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` which also did not work. After some time and nothing works, I shut it down again plugged my HDMI in the login screen, typed my password and UI works.

So anyone could help me understand what is happening here, what I can do to stop this problem, because looks like If I don't have a HDMI cable close to me this notebook will not work at all. This behavior started 1 week ago. Also worth mentioning that I'm not that experienced with Ubuntu and the terminal at all.

Ubuntu version: 22.04.3 LTS
OS Type: 64bit
GNOME version: 42.9

Comment: Have you solved this yet? I am having a very similar issue with my ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS going black right after trying to log in.
In one instance I was able to rm ~/.config/monitors.xml and log out and log in immediately, which only worked once, but not after another reboot.
In another instance, I was able to restart ubuntu just at the point BEFORE entering my login credentials, and this too worked, but not after another reboot.
In these two instances I did not have to physically disconnect my second monitor, but still these are not very fun workarounds.
My situation started two days ago after

Comment: Here is another twist to the issue, if you are using a laptop:

Leave your external monitor connected. Boot your laptop, and when it reaches the login prompt, don't log in just yet, close the laptop lid instead. At that point the primary monitor will become your external monitor and you *might* be able to proceed.

Comment: Man I have been having the same issue for the past few weeks. Pissing me off. Have to keep reverting back to kernel 5.15.84 on boot to be able to login. With kernels 5.15.86/87 as soon I try to type in password screen dies. Scary as hell.

Answer (score 1):

OS Name: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit
GNOME version: 42.9

I have two laptops with the above OS and both have been exhibiting display problems (crazy horizontal lines fill and mask the entire display screen). Here too the problem started a couple of days earlier after a bunch of system files got updated.

In one laptop, the problem would occur when the screen would go blank after a period of inactivity. I simply disabled the Screen Blank by choosing `Never` in the `Settings` -> `Power Savings Option`.

In the other laptop, the problem (Crazy horizontal lines) would occur when I would try to enter the password in the login screen. The workaround I chose was to enter the GRUB boot loader menu at the time of power on, by simply keeping the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key pressed. Click on `Advanced options for Ubuntu`, and choose `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-86-generic (recovery mode)`. If you wish to avoid `recovery mode`, you may experiment with the previous version say in my case - 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-84-generic' - worked fine too.

Hope the above workaround helps till the developers trace the issue and resolve it with a new update.

Comment: Thank you VKamat, what you said "you may experiment with the previous version say in my case - 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-84-generic' - worked fine too" that works for me. For the time being, it is a better path to success for me than trying to discover or tweak Linux 5.15.0-86-generic. I will set grub to default to Linux 5.15.0-84-generic and wait for a future update.