# Ubuntu Budgie 22.04.3 LTS with 5.15.0.86 generic lands at a blank green screen after login

Tags: drivers, kernel

Dears,
Firstly: I am not an Ubuntu expert, but I use Ubuntu during 80 or 90% of my 'on screen' time. The rest I need to boot Windows for a few rarely used applications.
The problem  is as described in the subject line. After logging in to the default Ubuntu, which runs with the 5.15.0.86 Ubuntu kernel, I do not get into the Budgie shell but to a green screen, with nothing else on it. I suspect, that the AMD driver is not accessible. Why do I suspect this? Maybe I give you an overview of my three OS installations. The Ubuntus run with the Budgie shell:

**- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS**

- The default Kernel in GRUB is 5.15.0.86 generic.
  Problem:   This is the one which ends up with the green screen and the secondary screen   black. During boot BEFORE I get to the UID/Password prompt I get about 20 lines with message like "Clearing orphaned inode xxxxxxx (uid=.......")
- I tried Ubuntu advanced options.
  -- If I manually select the Ubuntu advanced options and launch 5.15.0.86 generic in protected mode I can login and use the system with the main screen. No access to the secondary screen. If I start Reontop it does not show any reaction when I start graphics.   By the way I run a Captiva tower from Germany with an AMD A10-9700 Radeon R7, 10 Compute Cores 4C+6G.I assume in protected mode Ubuntu does not utilize the AMD driver. Sorry for my amateur statement.
  -- Advanced options with 5.15.0.84 generic protected mode is like the one above. Works, but not utilisation of AMD drivers (I think)
  -- Advanced options with 5.15.0.84 booted without restricting it works fine. I can login, work and have both screens working.

Consequence: For the time being 5.15.0.84 does its job. I am not a developer. As far as I understand the AMD driver come with the kernel. My amateur conclusion is: I might have problems accessing the AMD drivers in 5.15.0.86 due to the orphaned inodes. 5.15.0.84 did not show the 'orphaned inode' message an I can use it normally.

**- Windows 10:**
I do not see any graphics problems. No error messages. I can use both screens and the AMD tools do not indicate any problems either. Moreover it boots from a different SSD.

**- Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS**
I can use the default kernel and all versions, which are offered in the GRUB advanced menu. Nevertheless: Ubuntu 20 is just my fall back version.

*Questions:* a) Is there away to reload the AMD drivers into 5.15.0.86 or replace/update the whole kernel? Assuming that the AMD part of it is corrupted. YOu remember: My orphaned inodes and the fact, that the .84 kernel works. Mind: I cannot load the full 5.15.0.86 kernel based Ubuntu. Just the protected mode. So how would I do the update anyway?
b) As I am not a developer but user: Do I have to expect any disadvantages by just using the 5.15.0.84 kernel? If not, then I can continue using it and wait for the next Ubuntu LTS.

Tnx in advance and let me know, which information I should provide further.

Thomas

Comment: 22.04.3 uses 6.2 kernel by default. Have you tried it?

Comment: I am having similar issues and currently solving them booting with 5.15.84. Looks like others are having it too - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483151/ubuntu-22-04-not-loading-ui-after-login-getting-black-screen/1488271#1488271

Comment: I upgraded to 5.15.0-87. It works and 5.15.0-84 works too. What keeps me concerned. With...0-87 I get two "Clearing orphaned inode xxxxxxx (uid=.......") message lines. With ...0-84 I get them sometimes yes sometimes no. At least a big improvement to ..0-86 where I get about 20 and finally land in the 'green screen nirvana'. Is my SSD going to die? The SMART self test does not indicate problems. I always shutdown regularly. Except the green screen ;-)

Comment: I am closing the case. I an work with 5.15.0-84 and with 5.15.0-87.                       Sudo lshw -c video shows  my installed Display Controller and the AMDGPU driver. And 'Disks' tells me, that the file systems are OK and the SMART analysis tells also, that everything is fine. I will adapt GRUB accordingly in order to avoid booting with the 5.15.0-86 kernel.

Comment: Re the default kernel:  I installed 22.04.03 LTS earlier this year. It came with  5.15.0-84  and  5.15.0-86. GRUB used ...-86 as the default kernel. This week I ran the upgrade and got to ...-87. Also the SW updater tool does not get me to 6.2. I am just reading possible benfits of 6.2 and will install it later. Tnx for the hint!